# Android, SQLite: Как ПРАВИЛЬНО распределить код?

Tags: android, sqlite

В интернет источниках по работе `SQLite` в `Android` написано, что нужно унаследовать свой класс от `SQLiteOpenHelper` располагая данные о таблице в этом классе. Если таблиц больше чем 1, то данные о таблице и методы для работы с ней раздуют этот класс на много строк кода. Как правильно организовать разделение на сущности все таблицы?

Правильно ли будет:

1. Вынести в интерфейс все методы для работы с таблицей (`Table`)
2. Создать один класс для работы с БД унаследовав его от `SQLiteOpenHelper` (`DBHelper`)
3. Создать абстрактный класс для получения доступа к БД (`DataSource`)
4. Унаследовать конкретную реализацию от `DataSource` и реализовать от `Table` (`TableDataSource`)

Например:

`Table`:

```
public interface UserTable {

  String TABLE_NAME = "user";
  String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  String COLUMN_LOGIN = "login";
  String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "password";

  String CREATE_TABLE_REQUEST =
      "CREATE TABLE `" + TABLE_NAME + "` (" +
          COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
          COLUMN_LOGIN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
          COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT NOT NULL);";

  String UPGRADE_TABLE_REQUEST =
      "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `" + TABLE_NAME + "`;";

  String SELECT_LIMIT = "30";

  boolean findUser(String login);
  boolean findUser(String login, String password);
  boolean registerUser(String login, String password);
}
```

`DBHelper`:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static DatabaseHelper instance = null;

  public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null)
      instance = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    return instance;
  }

  private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    // Выполняем запросы создания таблиц
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // Выполняем запросы обновления таблиц
  }
}
```

`DataSource`:

```
public abstract class DataSource {

  private DatabaseHelper dbHelper = null;
  protected SQLiteDatabase db = null;

  protected DataSource(Context context) {
    dbHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(context);
  }

  public void open() {
    try {
      db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
      db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    }
  }

  public void close() {
    dbHelper.close();
  }
}
```

`TableDataSource`:

```
public class UserTableDataSource extends DataSource implements UserTable {

  public UserTableDataSource(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findUser(String login) {
    // Реализация метода
  }

  @Override
  public boolean findUser(String login, String password) {
    // Реализация метода
  }

  @Override
  public boolean registerUser(String login, String password) {
    // Реализация метода
  }
}
```

Comment: Не вижу ничего плохого, такой подход очень даже приемлемый. Делаю практически в таком же стиле. По факту, строгих гайдлайнов нет, поэтому - дело вкуса.

Comment: Еще есть вопрос о том, как добавлять запросы `CREATE_TABLE_REQUEST ` и `UPGRADE_TABLE_REQUEST` из таблицы `UserTable` в методы `onCreate()` и `onUpgrade()` класса `DBHelper`, чтоб эти методы небыли сильно связаны с переменными сущности?